# Why can't I connect Pgadmin from local machine to docker postgres but I can connect from a docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin-4

So I have a Postgres docker container running and I wanted to connect to it via Pgadmin installed on my machine (windows). I tried everything and it didn't work. I eventually installed another container with Pgadmin on it and it worked without a problem. Why would this happen ?

Edit:
These are the docker run parameters:

```
docker run --hostname=55c29504e819 --mac-address=02:42:ac:11:00:02 --env=POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root --env=POSTGRES_USER=root --env=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/15/bin --env=GOSU_VERSION=1.16 --env=LANG=en_US.utf8 --env=PG_MAJOR=15 --env=PG_VERSION=15.3-1.pgdg120+1 --env=PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data --volume=C:\Users\Mar\pg_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data --volume=/var/lib/postgresql/data -p 5432:5432 --restart=no --runtime=runc -d postgres
```

Comment: Could You provide a configuration for the problematic container?

Comment: It seems like you have a lot of irrelevant options in that `docker run` command (you should almost never need `docker run --mac-address` for example, and overriding the image's `PATH` at runtime seems odd); conversely, you haven't said how you're trying to connect to the database in the two setups.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?